# Compare Change in Richtextbox wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, compare, richtextbox

The WPF window has a Rich Text Box that loads a Xaml Package format,  I was able to program it to open, save and close the document.  Now, at the closing time, I was able to ask the user to save or not while closing, I was able to do that through a message box.

The problem is now that if the Rich Text Box is empty or if the user has not made any modifications to it, even then the question to save fires at closing.

I tried to compare the opening data with closing time data by comparing the richtextbox, flowdocument objects and text range objects but I do have any luck with them, could you please tell me how I can get a good compare/if any change occured. If use the change event of rich text box and use a flag, the work can be solved but if user reverts the changes the problem occurs again.

Looking for advice thank you.

Comment: Is comparing the return value of `RichTextBox.ToString()` an option?

Comment: But To string is not valid here because all it does is send Windows.RichtextBox I think.  I tried with Equal()

Answer (score 0):

set a flag to false when your window opens up indicating the that the rtb has not changed.

Handle the TextChanged event for your richtextbox, in the textchanged event subroutine set the flag that indicates if the rtb has changed or not to true.

at closing time check to the flag to see if it is true or false.

Of note, you will also need another flag to let the textchange subroutine know that your form is being initialized, because the textchange event fires when the rtb is initially loaded.   Just initialize this initial load flag as a local variable on the form with a value of true, and at the end of the forms load event set it to false.

In the textchange routine first check if the initial load is underway and if it is don't flip the rtb flag to true.

Comment: Yes, I already said this in the question, this method will fire save if the text is edited and undone the change by the user, example adding a line and removing the same to back.

Answer (score 0):

Compute a hash for your saved Xaml Package and the Xaml Package you want to save. If it is not equal save. [HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) takes a `Stream` or a `Byte[]`.

```
byte[] oldHashcode = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash( Stream or byte[] );
byte[] newHashcode = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash( Stream or byte[] );

if (!newHashcode.SequenceEqual(oldHashcode))
{
    ask the user to save
}
```

Comment: How can I get stream from the current RichText box?

Comment: How you save the content of the RichTextBox? What about Xaml Package format, could you use this to get a stream or a byte array?

Comment: Yes, I can the get the file stream before save/open time, but how to get stream before asking to save, do you meant o create a temp file then compare?

Comment: It hasn't be a temp file. Create just a MemoryStream for example, then compare the hash with the one from the open stream, ask the user and if confirmed save MemoryStream to file. Something along these lines.

Comment: I Tested now as you said, but the results are not reliable, I am getting them wrong some times.  Thank you.